# Set IntPtr value of COM DLL in VB.net project

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6

my task is to write a VB.NET library to interact with a piece of VB6 application. This VB6 application provides some unmanaged COM DLLs.

I created interop types (by using tlbimp) and added them as a reference in my VB.NET project.

Well, there is also an old VB6 project (library) existing, which is also referencing the (native) COM DLLs, let's call them 
`COM1.dll`, `COM2.dll` and `COM3.dll`.
This old project is having a "Class Module" called `claMod` where it is doing the following:

```
    Option Explicit
    Public Property Set GlobalProp(oObj As claClass1)
            Set COM1.MyPointer = oObj
            Set COM2.MyPointer = oObj
    End Property
```

where `claClass1` is a class in `COM3` and `COM1.MyPointer` and `COM2.MyPointer` are of type `System.IntPtr`.

My question is: How is possible to set these two pointers without declaring the corresponding objects (instances of COM1 and COM2) ?? And secondly, how can I do the same in my new VB.NET library?

Comment: They are references not pointers, the MyPointer property is of a type that is compatible with claClass1.  In your VB6 example COM1/2 must be instantiated somewhere ...

Comment: @AlexK. Must be instantiated somewhere, yes, but classes are automatically instantiated at runtime by setting their Instancing property to GlobalMultiUse.

Answer (score 1):

To allow referencing of COM1 and COM2 without specifically instantiating them, set each class's Instancing property to GlobalMultiUse. Then the code that you have in your post will work without having to create a reference to it.

There are many such objects already running in the VB6 environment; the `Screen` object is a familiar example.

This is basically the same as declaring a [`Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared) class in VB.Net or a `static` class in C#.